# Groupby и лямбда-выражение на Python

Tags: python

Имеется часть кода, и нужно объяснить, что этот код описывает.

```
groups = groupby(categories, key=lambda x: x[0])
    groups = [(group, [(cat[1] + u"--" + group, u'{} ({}, {})'.format(cat[1],
    cat[2], cat[3]) if cat[1] else cat[1]) for cat in cats]) for group, cats
    in groups]
```

Единственное, что я понял, так это группировка по какому-то значению с помощью лямбда-выражения.

Прошерстив некоторое количество информации в интернете, я так и не смог понять остальное.

Comment: проще всего объяснить это на примере, но для этого надо знать структуру `categories` и `cat`, а еще лучше привести тестовые данные для этих двух объектов. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Про группировку можно почитать в документации - и примеры там есть, и объяснение - https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Остальное - генератор списка (list comprehension). Можно развернуть в такой код:

```
new_groups = []
for group, cats in groups:
    group_element = [group]
    cats_elements = []
    for cat in cats:
        cats_element = [cat[1] + "--" + group] 
        if cat[1]:
            cats_element.append("{format_here}")
        else:
            cats_element.append(cat[1])
        cats_elements.append(tuple(cats_element))
    group_element.append(cats_elements)
    groups.append(tuple(group_element))
```

Ну а вообще - адок какой-то, не стоит так писать.

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) группирует смежные одинаковые элементы и генерирует пары `(ключ, "группа одинаковых значений")`, где каждое значение равно ключу согласно key функции.

Пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import groupby

for key, group in groupby("aabAa"):
    print(f"key={key}, group={list(group)}")

print('*' * 60)
for key, group in groupby("aabAa", key=str.casefold):
    print(f"key={key}, group={list(group)}")
```

#### Результат

```
key=a, group=['a', 'a']
key=b, group=['b']
key=A, group=['A']
key=a, group=['a']
************************************************************
key=a, group=['a', 'a']
key=b, group=['b']
key=a, group=['A', 'a']
```

Видно, что группируются только те одинаковые значения, которые идут подряд. По умолчанию, если key функция не указана, то значения сравниваются напрямую, то есть `key=lambda x: x`.

`key=str.casefold` говорит, что символы сравниваются без учёта регистра. Это пример показывает, что любую функцию можно передать, а не только `lambda` (что естественно: [функции, создаваемые lambda, имеют тот же тип что и функции, создаваемые def-конструкцией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612885/23044)).