# Как работают lambda-функции?

Tags: python, python-3.5

Смотрю чужой код, и не знаю что это за функция, точнее её 2-я строчка, где можно почитать про такие конструкции? И как это работает?

```
def get_biggest_bar(bars):
    result = max(bars, key=lambda tmp: tmp.get("SeatsCount", float('inf')))
    return result['Name']
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Зачем нужны Lambda-функции?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534344/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lambda-функции это упрощение для программистов - вместо написания отдельной функции для одного выражения, можно использовать однострочный вариант, который сразу передастся как объект.

Пример:

```
>>> x = lambda y: y*2
>>> x(2)
4
```

При этом не надо использовать `return`.

В вашем случае lambda-функция передается как аргумент `key` функции `max`, которая получает аналог этой функции:

```
def f(tmp):
    return tmp.get("SeatsCount", float('inf'))
```

Answer (score 3):

У анонимных функций по умолчанию встроен оператор `return` - это означает, что анонимные функции работают только с выражениями которые возвращают данные.

У анонимных функций нет названий (за исключением определения в переменной) и начинается с зарезервированного слова `lambda`.

```
print (lambda x,y: x*y)(10,20)
print (lambda x: True if x % 2 == 0 else False)(10)
```

[4.7.5. Lambda Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Выражение `lambda x: x*x`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) создаёт анонимную функцию, которая ведёт себя как:

```
def <lambda>(x):
    return x*x
```

Типы создаваемых функций совершенно одинаковы, разница только в наличии/отсутствии имени и ограничения на код до одного выражения внутри lambda.

```
>>> print(*range(-10, 0))
-10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
>>> max(range(-10, 0))
-1
>>> max(range(-10, 0), key=lambda x: x*x)
-10
>>> def square(x):
...     return x*x
...     
>>> max(range(-10, 0), key=square)
-10
```