# Странное поведение itertools.groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имею странное поведение `groupby`. Впечатление такое, что он игнорирует неотсортированные элементы.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> arr = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
>>> groups = groupby(arr)
>>> {x: list(y) for x, y in groups}
{1: [1], 2: [2], 3: [3]}
>>> arr.sort()
>>> groups = groupby(arr)
>>> {x: list(y) for x, y in groups}
{1: [1, 1, 1], 2: [2, 2, 2], 3: [3, 3, 3]}
```

Почему так происходит?

PS: версия 3.6.0

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Groupby и лямбда-выражение на Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533292/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) про это написано : `The operation of groupby() is similar to the uniq filter in Unix. It generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes.`

Т.е. каждый раз когда вы натыкаетесь, например, на 1, у вас сбрасывается ключ, поэтому, в вашем случае, вы имеете по одному значению для неотсортированного списка.

```
from itertools import groupby
arr = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1,2,3]
groups = groupby(arr)
print({x: list(y) for x, y in groups})
```

На выходе получите: `{1: [1, 1], 2: [2], 3: [3]}`

Comment: Спасибо. То есть без сорта - никуда?

Comment: Да, без сортировки тут не обойтись.

Answer (score 2):

В документации написано:

> Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.

[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby%20itertools.groupby)

Т. е. предварительно последовательность должна быть сортирована с применением того же ключа, что и группировка.
Потому как groupby группирует элементы с одинаковым ключом расположенные последовательно.

В явном виде это можно увидеть в следующем коде:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> arr = [1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
>>> groups = groupby(arr)
>>> [x: list(y) for x, y in groups]
[(1, [1]), (2, [2]), (3, [3]), (1, [1, 1]), (2, [2, 2]), (3, [3, 3]), (1, [1, 1, 1]), (2, [2, 2, 2]), (3, [3, 3, 3])]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)<sup>*</sup> группирует **смежные** идущие подряд одинаковые значения:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for _, group in groupby("aabbaaabbb"):
...     print(*group)
a a
b b
a a a
b b b
```

Вы видите только последние группы для каждого ключа, так как вы результат в словарь записываете (`{1: [1], 1: [2]} == {1: [2]}`).

Если вы хотите, чтобы все одинаковые значения в одну группу попали, то либо надо сортировать ввод:

```
>>> for _, group in groupby(sorted("aabbaaabbb")):
...     print(*group)
a a a a a
b b b b b
```

или использовать другие подходы, к примеру, на основе словарей, которые не обращают внимание на порядок элементов (сортировка не нужна):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("aabbaaabbb")
Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 5})  # элемент и количество повторений
```

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>Первое предложение в описании [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):</sub>

> Make an iterator that returns **consecutive** keys and groups from the iterable.<sup>выделение моё</sup>